# UIKit rotate view 90 degrees while keeping the bounds to edge

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, cgaffinetransform

**Update**:

I have since tried setting my layer anchor paint to (0,0) and translate it back to frame (0,0) after rotation using this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-change-a-views-anchor-point-without-moving-it).

This, however, still doesn't address the early wrapping issue. See below. Setting the content inset on the right side (bottom side) does not work.

```
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.height, height: view.bounds.width)
    print(textView.frame)
    textView.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    
    textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2));
    print(textView.frame)
    textView.transform = textView.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -(view.bounds.width))
    
    print(textView.frame)
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: height, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[image]

**Original question:**
I want to rotate the only UIView in subview clockwise by 90 degrees while keeping its bounds to edges of the screen, that is, below the Navigation Bar and above the Tab Bar and in between two sides.

Normally there are two ways to do this, either set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true and set subview.frame = view.bounds

or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false and add four anchors constraints (top, bottom,leading, trailing) to view's four anchor constrains.

This is what it usually will do.
[image]

However, if I were to rotate the view while keeping its bound like before, like below, how would I do that?

[image]

Here's my current code to rotate a UITextView 90 degrees clockwise. I don't have a tab bar in this case but it shouldn't matter. Since before the textview grows towards the bottom, after rotation the textview should grow towards the left side. The problem is, it's not bound to the edge I showed, it is behind the nav bar.

```
var textView = UITextView()
view.addSubview(textView)
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2));
textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
```

[image]

Here it completely disappears if I rotate it after setting the frames

[image]

I also tried adding arbitrary value to the textView's y frame like so

```
textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
```

but the result is that words get wrapped before they reach the bottom edge.

[image]

I also tried adding constrains by anchor and setting translateautoresizingmaskintoconstraints to false

```
 constraints.append(contentsOf: [
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
```

but the result is still a white screen.

Besides what I showed, I experimented with a lot of things, adding bit of value here and there, but they all are kind of a hack and doesn't really scale. For example, if the device gets rotated to landscape mode, the entire view gets screwed up again.

So, my question is, what is the correct, scalable way to do this? I want to have this rotated textview that is able to grow(scroll) towards the left and correctly resized on any device height and any orientation.

I know this could be related to anchor point. But since I want my view to actually bound to edges and not just display its content like an usual rotated UIImage. What are the steps to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to embed the `UITextView` in a `UIView` "container" ... constraining it to that container ... and then rotate the **container** view.

Because the `textView` will continue to have a "normal" rotation ***relative to its superview,*** it will behave as desired.

Quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textView = UITextView()
    let containerView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // we're going to explicitly set the container view's frame
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
        containerView.addSubview(textView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        // we'll inset the textView by 8-points on all sides
        //  so we can see that it's inside the container view
        
        // avoid auto-layout error/warning messages
        let cTrailing = textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        cTrailing.priority = .required - 1
        
        let cBottom = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        cBottom.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            // activate trailing and bottom constraints
            cTrailing, cBottom,
            
        ])
        
        textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32.0, weight: .regular)
        
        textView.text = "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, and then goes to the kitchen to get some dinner."
        
        // so we can see the framing
        textView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        containerView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // inset the container view frame by 40
        //  leaving some empty space around it
        //  so we can tap the view
        containerView.frame = view.frame.insetBy(dx: 40.0, dy: 40.0)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // end editing if textView is being edited
        view.endEditing(true)
        
        // if container view is NOT rotated
        if containerView.transform == .identity {
            // rotate it
            containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2));
        } else {
            // set it back to NOT rotated
            containerView.transform = .identity
        }
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

tapping anywhere white (so, tapping the controller's view instead of the container or the textView itself) will toggle rotated/non-rotated:

[image]

**Edit** - *responding to comment...*

The reason we have to work with the `frame` is because of the way `.transform` works.

When we apply a `.transform` it changes the **frame** of the view, but not its **bounds**.

Take a look at this quick example:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let greenLabel = UILabel()
    let yellowLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        greenLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yellowLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(greenLabel)
        view.addSubview(yellowLabel)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            yellowLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            yellowLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            yellowLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            yellowLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            greenLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yellowLabel.topAnchor),
            greenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yellowLabel.leadingAnchor),
            greenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yellowLabel.trailingAnchor),
            greenLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yellowLabel.bottomAnchor),

        ])
        
        yellowLabel.text = "Yellow"
        greenLabel.text = "Green"
        
        yellowLabel.textAlignment = .center
        greenLabel.textAlignment = .center

        yellowLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.80)
        greenLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
        // we'll give the green label a larger, red font
        greenLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 48.0, weight: .bold)
        greenLabel.textColor = .systemRed
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // if yellow label is NOT rotated
        if yellowLabel.transform == .identity {
            // rotate it
            yellowLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2));
        } else {
            // set it back to NOT rotated
            yellowLabel.transform = .identity
        }
        
        print("Green  - frame: \(greenLabel.frame) bounds: \(greenLabel.bounds)")
        print("Yellow - frame: \(yellowLabel.frame) bounds: \(yellowLabel.bounds)")

    }

}
```

We've created two labels, with the yellow label on top of the green label, and the green label constrained top/leading/trailing/bottom to the yellow label.

Notice that when we apply a rotation transform to the yellow label, the green label does not change.

[image]

If you look at the debug console output, you'll see that the yellow label's **frame** changes, but its **bounds** stays the same:

```
// not rotated
Green  - frame: (87.5, 303.5, 200.0, 80.0) bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 80.0)
Yellow - frame: (87.5, 303.5, 200.0, 80.0) bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 80.0)
// rotated
Green  - frame: (87.5, 303.5, 200.0, 80.0) bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 80.0)
Yellow - frame: (147.5, 243.5, 80.0, 200.0) bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 80.0)
```

So... to make use of auto-layout / constraints, we want to create a custom `UIView` subclass, which has the "container" view and the text view. Something like this:

```
class RotatableTextView: UIView {
    
    public var containerInset: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var textViewInset: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            tvConstraints[0].constant = textViewInset
            tvConstraints[1].constant = textViewInset
            tvConstraints[2].constant = -textViewInset
            tvConstraints[3].constant = -textViewInset
        }
    }
    
    public let textView = UITextView()
    
    public let containerView = UIView()
    
    private var tvConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // we're going to explicitly set the container view's frame
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
        containerView.addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(containerView)
        
        // avoid auto-layout error/warning messages
        var c: NSLayoutConstraint!
        
        c = textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: textViewInset)
        tvConstraints.append(c)
        
        c = textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: textViewInset)
        tvConstraints.append(c)
        
        c = textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -textViewInset)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        tvConstraints.append(c)
        
        c = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -textViewInset)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        tvConstraints.append(c)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(tvConstraints)
                
    }
    func toggleRotation() {
        // if container view is NOT rotated
        if containerView.transform == .identity {
            // rotate it
            containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2));
        } else {
            // set it back to NOT rotated
            containerView.transform = .identity
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var r = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: frame.size)
        containerView.frame = r.insetBy(dx: containerInset, dy: containerInset)
    }
    
}
```

Now, in our controller, we can use constraints on our custom view like we always do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let rotTextView = RotatableTextView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        rotTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(rotTextView)
        
        // we'll inset the custom view on all sides
        //  so we can tap on the "root" view to toggle the rotation

        let inset: CGFloat = 20.0
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            rotTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: inset),
            rotTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: inset),
            rotTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -inset),
            rotTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -inset),
            
        ])

        // let's use a 32-point font
        rotTextView.textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32.0, weight: .regular)
        
        // give it some initial text
        rotTextView.textView.text = "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, and then goes to the kitchen to get some dinner."
        
        // if we want to inset either the container or the text view
        //rotTextView.containerInset = 8.0
        //rotTextView.textViewInset = 4.0
        
        // so we can see the framing if insets are > 0
        //  if both insets are 0, we won't see these, so they don't need to be set
        //rotTextView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        //rotTextView.containerView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // let's set the text view background color to light-cyan
        //  so we can see its frame
        rotTextView.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // end editing if textView is being edited
        view.endEditing(true)
        
        rotTextView.toggleRotation()
        
    }
    
}
```

Note that this is just ***Example Code***, but it should get you on your way.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I never thought of wrapping it with another UIView could have this effect! Will try this when I get home. Will give you an upvote first.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using autoLayout rather than directly setting the containerView frame.  I can't see a way to force the constraints to adapt to the post-transform geometry (or even be sure they are still relevant)?

Comment: @flanker - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag for a thorough edit.  I was getting there slowly but you've saved me a lot of work! I always struggle conceptually when using both frames and autolayout as logically (to me!) the anchors/constraints should relate to the frame.

Comment: Hi I tried this out and I found the textview is still behind the navigation bar. By your didlayoutsubview shouldn't it adjust to the bounds without the nabber(if present)?

Comment: @yaozhang - yes, you should always respect the safe-area. The example above was simply to show how to rotate the text view without changing the text-container width. If you're using the `didLayoutSubviews` approach, you'd want to set the frame relative to the safe-area margins. Not also, that this simple, example code does not address what to do when the keyboard is displayed. That's up to the app developer to handle :)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your comment! I am new to textview and manipulating it is quite difficult. I am encounter another textview bug that I couldn't find any good resource online, I figure you know what is going on. Could you also take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416877/uitextview-shows-extra-space-when-font-size-is-changed-while-at-in-the-middle-of